# Getting string Id from a Adapterview

Tags: java, android, android-adapterview

So I have the following code

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        switch (selectedItem) {
            case "Lowest Price":// handle...
                break;
            case "Price": // handle...
                break;
            default: break;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

but I have already have the strings in a string file which populate the adapter.

Is there a way to get the id from parent or view so that I can do something like this:

```
switch(id)
case R.resource.my_string
```

Answer (score 0):

If you String array in your string.xml like this,

```
<array name="price_type">
    <item>Lowest Price</item>
    <item>Price</item>
</array>
```

you can directly get the value from array like this,

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    final String[] priceValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.price_type);

    String selectedItem = priceValues[position];

    // if you want to use more manipulation based on the item you can use the position of the value.

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```